# .NET 7 framework does not show up in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-7.0

After a long absence of C# I re-installed Visual Studio Community Version 2022 17.4.3.

Then I installed `dotnet-sdk-7.0.101-win-x64`.

Then I try to start a new console .NET application but I don't have the option to chose the .NET 7 framework. It goes only to up to to 4.8. Is that normal? What should I do to make version 7 visible?

[image: Shows my framework options]

Comment: Pay attention to the project template you selected to get started.  You picked one with ".NET Framework" in its name, gives you the legacy framework choices.  You want one with just ".NET" in its name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating an application be sure to select correct template - ***Console App*** (without additional remarks):

[image]

You have selected a template targeting .NET Framework which does not allow  targeting .NET (i.e. .NET Core) runtime by default.

Answer (score 16):

Manually update Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version.

For some reason it doesn't automatically update to 17.5.x, which is required for .NET 7.0

Comment: what's the easiest way to update from 17.1 without downloading entire package of vs2022?

Comment: @PhilippMunin go to Help tab -> Check for Updates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it got solved by doing the following:

1- open visual studio installer
2- on workloads tab check the following

- .Net Desktop Development
- Azure Development
- ASP.Net and web development

3- hit modify

After that I was able to see .net6, .net7 in the frameworks drop down

Answer (score 0):

In mi case the only way to solve it was to get it from microsoft's dotnet site, make sure to download the SDK Framework and not the runtime version and then you will see the installed one after run the dotnet--list-sdks

[image: dotnetlist]